# GWT + Editor: Avoid removing violation messages and wrong input

Tags: gwt, bean-validation

We implement in our **GWT/GXT** project displays that contain in most cases a filter form and a grid to show the filtered data. Displays are implemented with **UiBinder** and the "**Gwt Editor Framework**".

The user wants to have validations on the filter form. To do the validation we use **JSR303 bean validation**. The validation must apply on each change of a field in a filter form. The user wants also to have a kind of **automatic fill a field** based on the input in a second field (lets say a number range from and to). That works all perfect - but...

We struggle in a particular situation:
The user starts to type in some data in the filter form.
He puts a wrong value in a field that has to be parsed into a date (for example).
He continues typing into following fields which then cause an automatic prefill of a second field.
The result is currently, that the wrong value he typed into the date field is removed and the violation message as well.

Our current implementation will do a `flush()` to get the values the user typed in already. After that we fill a attribute in the model (based on the input) and do an `edit(model)`. If there are some violation messages because of a wrong input in a different field in that filter form, the value is removed. That happens on field that need a parse (date, time, number).

The question is now:
Is there a way to keep the wrong value and the violation message as well?
Thank you for any replay!

Comment: I'm surprised it does that. I'm afraid we don't use GXT but standard Widgets/UIBinder/EditorFramework doesn't do that. Are you also using the RequestFactory?  Maybe it is that your date entry field is refreshing in some way and won't hold invalid value?  Is it a date that can't be parsed our just in the wrong date range?

Comment: We do not use RequestFactory. And yes, the value the user typed in can not be parsed. I was not clear enough - sorry for that!

Comment: We use RequestFactoryDelegate, so an "official" binding and it does this too. So our app does it. Sucks, although nobody has complained. I can't think of a nice solution. Maybe the widget could hold the bad value unless it sees a setValue of something new. Or even worse use a String for the Editor.

Comment: Or could it just be the DateBox itself? OnBlur it will try and contain a valid value. Does your bad value persist if the box just loses focus?

Comment: Yes it is still there ...